# Current density operator 2nd quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I have two questions on the current operator.

In analogy to standard quantum mechanics, the 2nd quantized probability current density is given by

$\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r})=-i\frac{\hbar}{2m}\left[\Psi^{\dagger}(\mathbf{r})\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r})-\left(\nabla\Psi^{\dagger}(\mathbf{r})\right)\Psi(\mathbf{r})\right]$

My first question: Do we obtain that by just replacing the wave fn with the field operator $\psi \longrightarrow \Psi$?

(And how is the derivative of an operator to be understood?)

Further, I'd like to calculate the current-current correlation function

$C(\mathbf{r}\tau;\mathbf{r'}\tau')=-\langle T\{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}\tau)\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r'}\tau')\}\rangle$

I see that this will be evantually some kind of 4-point function (or two particle Green function). The book that I use (Transport in nanostructures by Ferry, page 174) brings the current operator to the form

$\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\hbar\mathbf{k}}{m} \Psi^{\dagger}\Psi(\mathbf{r})$

where k is the momentum. This yields just the regular density-density correlation function. I do not see how they get this result. It makes sense, since it corresponds to the standard definition of the current density $j=velocity*density$ but when I do the FT I get something like

$\mathbf{j}(p)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k}\mathbf{k}a^{\dagger}_{k+p/2}a^{\phantom{\dagger}}_{k-p/2}$

However, in the book Mahan, they just ignore the momentum dependence and set p=0. Can anyone help me figure out how to arrive at $\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\hbar\mathbf{k}}{m} \Psi^{\dagger}\Psi(\mathbf{r})$?